# How to open file from ssh server on the emacs terminal?

Tags: emacs

I'm new to emacs and a little confused about opening a saved file on an ssh client so I can edit it (this is for school)

What I have done is...

1. Opened my terminal on mac
2. Opened emacs via terminal
3. Split emacs screen so I have one side to edit a c program and another   side for terminal (to compile faster)
4. Logged onto an ssh client (there is a file on there that I'm supposed to edit)

The only problem is that I'm unsure how to open that specific file from my emacs terminal if that file is from an ssh client.

I have tried emacs filename.c on the emacs terminal & it opens a version of my file that isn't colored and scrolls oddly. 
How can I correctly open the file so that it's colored and scrolls like the regular files on emacs?

I have also tried c-c c-f on terminal and typed my filename.c but it just opens a blank page.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't spam tags! And this is not about programming, but using standard computer programs.

Comment: And you should probably look into sshfs

Comment: This is some Tramp doc to complement Michael's answer: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/TRAMP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs can access files on a remote machine via its package Tramp. In order to open such a file from your local machine, apply

> C-x C-f /ssh:user@host:/path/to/file

`user` is your login name at the remote machine, and `host` is the name of that machine.